# The multi-part identifier "INSERTED. " could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a trigger : if exists record in a table, update another table and if not exist insert to that table
I got an error to create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_update_laststatus_on_membersservices ON [dbo].[activemembers] AFTER 
INSERT AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS    
   (
   SELECT 1   
   FROM [membersservices] 
WHERE [membersservices].[mobilenumber] = INSERTED.[mobilenumber]
    AND [membersservices].[sid] = INSERTED.[sid]    
)    
BEGIN
  UPDATE membersservices  
  SET  membersservices.[last_status] = INSERTED.enable
  WHERE membersservices.mobilenumber=INSERTED.mobilenumber and membersservices.[sid]=INSERTED.[sid]
END
ELSE
    INSERT INTO membersservices VALUES ( INSERTED.[mobilenumber] ,INSERTED.[sid] ,INSERTED.[enable] , INSERTED.[dt] ); 
end
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier “INSERTED.mobilenumber” could not be bound

Answer (score 7):

INSERTED is a (pseudo)table, so it **must** appear in a FROM clause, every time you use it:

```
SELECT 1   
   FROM [membersservices] 
   JOIN INSERTED on ...  <--- you're missing this
WHERE [membersservices].[mobilenumber] = INSERTED.[mobilenumber]
    AND [membersservices].[sid] = INSERTED.[sid]  


UPDATE membersservices  
 SET  membersservices.[last_status] = INSERTED.enable
FROM membersservices     
JOIN INSERTED ON ...  <-- you're missing this


INSERT INTO membersservices (...)
SELECT ...
FROM INSERTED ...  <-- you're missing this
```

Other than that your logic is incorrect under concurrency. You should use a single [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to do both the update and insert.

Answer (score 1):

INSERTED is a table you have to join or do subqueries against. 
Remember that you can insert more than one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your referencing of `INSERTED`try changing it to:

**Full Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_update_laststatus_on_membersservices 
               ON [dbo].[activemembers] AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS    
    (
        SELECT 1   
        FROM [membersservices] ms
        JOIN INSERTED i ON ms.[mobilenumber] = i.[mobilenumber] 
                       AND ms.[sid] = i.[sid]    
    )    
        BEGIN
            UPDATE membersservices  
            SET  membersservices.[last_status] = i.enable
            FROM INSERTED i
            WHERE membersservices.mobilenumber = i.mobilenumber 
              and membersservices.[sid] = i.[sid]
        END
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO membersservices (mobilenumber, sid, enable, dt)
        (SELECT mobilenumber, sid, enable, dt FROM INSERTED)
END
```

Comment: If you want to write a `SELECT` for the rows of an `INSERT` statement, you omit the `VALUES` and the `()` associated with it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks was just busy editing it